# HTML/CSS : I can't add some margin's in a span next to a floated element

Tags: html, css, css-float

i try to have a floated image and a paragraph behind it. But i want the paragraph to start a at the middle so basically there not align. so i want to put margin-top on my span but failed of doing that.

e.g for my codes

```html
<div class="container">
  <article>
    <section>
      <p>
        <img style="float:left;" src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" />
        <span style="margin-top: 25px;">Hello World! My name is James polar Good morning</span>
      </p>
    </section>
  </article>
</div>
```

codepen: http://codepen.io/pango143/pen/LWJpmL

Comment: `<span>` is an inline element, where top margins and paddings do not apply. You might want to set it to `display: inline-block`

Comment: making the display inline-block will put the span content below the image.

Comment: but thanks for the info i have idea now. if u have idea how to fix this comment answer so i can upvote thanks

Comment: Then you might want to tweak with either the `vertical-align` property of the image element, or use a flexbox model to position everything so that they are vertically centered.

Comment: You could put `vertical-align: middle;` on both the span and the image and remove the float and margin

Comment: @PhilS i tried ur suggestion but when the paragraph is too long the next line is so far from the first line i mean its under the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can fix it with **line-height** property.

Add following css code to the span element

```
line-height: 110px;
```

OR

set **display: table;** to parent element and **display: table-cell;  vertical-align: middle;** to the child element. and just because your image contains shadows and it makes an eye think that image ends earlier than it actually does, you can move it down with margin-top propery.

Here is your css:

```
section p {
  display: table;
}

section p span {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

section p img {
  margin-top: 25px;
}
```

Comment: changing the line-height solve the starting point of the span content but destroy the whole text on it if the message is too long

Comment: @Arnoldwannabe I've edited post with another solution

Comment: thanks work for me :) thanks for terry useful comment too for telling me span is an inline element. up voting u guys.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a display inline-block to the element:

```html
<div class="container">

  <article>
    
    <section>
      
      <p>
          <img style="float:left;" src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" />
        <span style="margin-top: 45px; display:inline-block;">Hello World! My name is James polar Good morning</span>
      </p>
      
    </section>
  
  </article>


</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

By behind you mean something like this?

```html
<div class="container">

  <article>

<section>
  
  <div>
      <img style="position: absolute;" src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" />
    <p style="padding-top: 40px;">Hello World! My name is James polar Good morning</p>
  </div>
  
</section>
  
  </article>


</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to convert your span tag to `block label element`

```
span {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 25px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<div class="main-container">
  <article>
    <section>
      <div class="container" style="position: relative;">
         <img style="" src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg">
         <span style="position: absolute; padding-left: 13px; top: 50%;">Hello World! My name is James polar Good morning</span>
      </div>
    </section>
  </article>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can do this with diplay-inline and vertical-align: middle

```css
img {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
span {
 display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-top: -73px; /*ajust */
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 70%;
}
p {
  position :relative;
  width: 100%;
  font-size:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <article>
    
    <section>
      
      <p>
          <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" />
        <span>Hello World! My name is James polar Good morning</span>
      </p>
      
    </section>
  
  </article>


</div>
```

Comment: Perfect ! Keep it simple is always the thing to do !